# PHP Nested Static Variable Access for Dependency Injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection, static-variables

I would like to use this pattern to enable dependency injection in my code.
I feel that it keeps with the play-doh nature of dynamic languages [1].

```
class A {
  static $FOO = 'Foo';
  function __construct() {
    $this->foo = self::$FOO::getInstance();
  }
}

A::$FOO = 'MockFoo';
$a = new A();
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in [test.php] on line 6
```

I can create a temporary variable to trick the parser, but is there another way?

```
function __construct() {
  $FOO = self::$FOO;                                                                                                                                            
  $this->foo = $FOO::getInstance();
}
```

[1] http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/11/9/legos-play-doh-and-programming

Comment: Maybe this works: `$this->foo = {self::$FOO}::getInstance();`, but I dunno. However I wonder what kind of dependency injection this should be? Inject global state? Would be somewhat superfluous.

Comment: So in this case, I'm working with a legacy rails-like framework that uses a large number of static classes that are used pervasively. So assuming I have to make a call to Foo::getInstance(), and I can't outright replace Foo throughout the app/test suite (and I can't change the constructor args) is there another way to inject an instance of Foo?

Comment: $this->foo = {self::$FOO}::getInstance() results in a "syntax error, unexpected '{'" this is php 5.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no alternative syntax to accomplish this. You need a temporary variable to trick the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$class = self::$FOO;
$this->foo = $class::getInstance();
```